# Structure to represent files under a directory

Tags: unix, data-structures, filesystems

I am trying to define data structures for a filesystem. I understand that both files and directories are represented by inodes, with one bit to differentiate between the two.

However, I am not able to understand how to get files present under a particular directory. In Unix Filesystem, I am not seeing any structure to point to child inodes?
Is there a structure which does that? If not, how do I get files present under a directory? And if both are represented by same data structure (inode), what does child inodes in directories point to?

Answer (score 1):

*struct dirent* is used to represent directory entry which can be a file or another directory, check it's definition in the manual (http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir for instance). You can see this structure contains inode number, type of file and so on. By using functions *opendir* and *readdir* one can traverse filesystem, check [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612176/5428089).